# npm install sails tries to install less at version 1.7.5

Tags: ubuntu, less, npm, sails.js

I'm installing sails on Ubuntu with; 
node -v 0.12.2 
and npm -v 2.7.4.

`npm install sails` errors with;

```
sails@0.11.0 preinstall /home/ubuntu/sails/node_modules/sails
node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
npm WARN deprecated node-switchback@0.0.4: The 'node-switchback' NPM module is now simply 'switchback'. See https://github.com/node-machine/switchback for latest docs.
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme:https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
npm WARN deprecated node-switchback@0.0.2: The 'node-switchback' NPM module is now simply 'switchback'. See https://github.com/node-machine/switchback for latest docs.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing uglify-js@2.3.6
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-5-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! file /home/ubuntu/.npm/less/1.7.5/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/ubuntu/.npm/less/1.7.5/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/sails/npm-debug.log
```

Seems to be pointing at an old version of less 1.7.5. I'm able to `npm install less` at 2.5

I've opened an issue on [Sails' github repo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2826). Additional details developing there.

Answer (score 1):

Error `code EJSONPARSE` is an issue with the `package.json`. When you install a node package it stores the `package.json` file in a `.npm` folder. It seems you have a corrupted less 1.7.5 package file downloaded in your `.npm` folder.

Run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.npm/less/1.7.5/
```

This removed the local less `package.json` file on your computer so it pulls from NPMs servers. Now you can try installing Sails again.

Comment: I tested this on an older version of Node but I was able to recreate your issue and fix it. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error msg would contain following msg-

npm ERR! Failed to parse json

npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! ^

npm ERR! File: /home/user/path_to_corrupted_file

use this path to remove the corrupted file and run the npm install again.